# how to inc a pointer to variable? ASSEMBLER

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, increment, intel

How to inc a pointer of variable?
I want to move the pointer by 4 bits.
I have this: (BCD should hold 32 bits)

```
section .data  
BCD:  DQ 0

mov dword [BCD], 0
ADD BCD, 4
```

and when compiling I get this error:

> error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>   ** Intel proccessor
>   what's the problem?

Thank you

Comment: No, which _assembler_? (masm, nasm, tasm, fasm,...)

Comment: x86? BCD is not a register in that case

Comment: `BCD` is a label, so its address is given by the linker. You can't change what `BCD` refers to at run-time. You can only change the contents at the location it refers to.

Comment: x86 yes. And I know, I don't want to use registers that's why I defined it as variable. (I use the other registers for other purposes)

Comment: @Michael, how can I do it?

Comment: Well then you can't use it like a register :p. Also note that ADD <reg>,4 (when reg is a memory address) will increase that memory address by 4 bytes, not bits.

Comment: OK, so how can I increase by 4 bits and not bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the address in a register if you want to change it:

```
mov ebx,BCD       ; put the address of BCD in ebx
mov dword [ebx],0 ; store 0 in the first DWORD at BCD
add ebx,4         ; Move the pointer 4 bytes ahead
```

Comment: If you want to move by 4 **bytes** (not bits), you may also do
**mov dword [BCD+4],0**